# Adding an inputType prevents editText from re sizing

Tags: android, android-edittext, resize

basically adding an inputType to a textView will stop it from changing the number of lines.
ie: without inputType when you reach the end of an editText it will grow in size and you will continue typing on the second line, in the case of adding the inputType you simply scroll sideways

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

so how can I get both inputType and automatic re sizing?

Comment: Problem is in the inputType you are using. The textPersonName dosnt allow you to have more than one linse. Use inputtype text to achive this.

Comment: swing and a miss there buddy, I had already tried that, not to mention my textPostalAddress doesn't do it either.

Comment: Whats the root layout you are using ? Relative layout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="5" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: Wow, I really derped there, never noticed that as an option, used |textMultiLine on all my editTexts and worked like a charm.

Cheers mate!